# foward typedef structures

Tags: c, struct, typedef, forward-declaration

```
gcc 4.4.4 c89
```

I have this in my header file.

port.h

```
struct struct_tag;

int initialize_ports(struct_tag *port);
```

In my implemenation file I have this:

port.c

```
typedef struct struct_tag {
    int port_id;
} Port_t;
```

And in my driver.h file, I have the following:

```
#include "port.h"
int initialize_ports(struct_tag *port)
{
    port = malloc(sizeof *port);
    /* do checking here */
}
```

I have forward declared the structure, as I want to hide the internal elements.

However, I am getting the following error on my initialize_ports in the header file:

```
expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
```

I am just wondering how can I forward declare and be able to pass the structure as a parameter?

Many thanks for any advice,

Comment: You want to hide the internal elements, but right now you're hiding them from your own code. `driver.h` needs to have access to the definition in `port.c`, which needs to be in a file more appropriate for including somewhere. (Also `.c` files generally contain code instead of just type definitions.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As other answers have noted, you *could* change `struct_tag` to `struct struct_tag` in the prototype. Another way of getting your code to compile is to write

```
typedef struct struct_tag struct_tag;
```

in place of your existing `struct struct_tag;` (i.e. combine the typedef with the forward definition). That then does allow you to write

```
int initialize_ports(struct_tag *port)
```

without compile failures. However, this is still not quite what you want, because the caller can neither allocate a local variable of this type, nor malloc() one - because they don't know the size.

Other answers have suggested that you should open up the definition of the structure. That's generally not the right answer - because it removes the abstraction layer you're trying to create. Much better to have functions (in the `port.c`, i.e. the library that *does* know about the internals) such as:

```
struct_tag *create_port(...);
void free_port(struct_tag *port)
```

i.e. to create and free the structures - and indeed for other operations (such as reading from / writing to the structure) too.

Comment: +1 for suggesting moving the initialize/create into port.c.  Technically free_port doesn't *need* to go there, but it's the logical place.

Comment: Thanks :) It's good practice to have a free_port() function, because the port structure may itself contain pointers to other structures that also need to be freed when the port is freed...

Answer (score 8):

You should use:

```
int initialize_ports(struct struct_tag *port);
                     ^^^^^^
```

Also, forward declarations give you an *incomplete type* which you don't know the size of. If you need to allocate a `struct struct_tag` you need to include the full definition for it. Alternatively you could use some `create_struct_tag()` function if you want to make it fully opaque.

Answer (score 2):

You'll get an error as you don't KNOW the size of "port" as all it has to go on is the forward declaration.

In summary you are best off not using a forward declaration here unless you also set a constant value that is the sizeof "struct_tag" ... You would most likely be best off just fully declaring it.

Comment: Parentheses are only needed with `sizeof` for types, so `sizeof *port` is fully valid (except that, as you mention, the size isn't known in that spot).

Answer (score 2):

The `sizeof` operator is evaluated at *compile time* not runtime, so at the line:

```
port = malloc(sizeof *port);
```

the compiler has no information regarding the size of the structure.

Solutions include:

- fully define the type in the header file.
- define `initialize_ports()` in port.c *after* the struct is fully defined.
- have `initialize_ports()` call a function defined in ports.c to get the size of `Port_t` at run-time.

In any case you should *not* define `initialize_ports()` in the header file driver.h unless your compiler supports the `inline` or `_inline` keyword *and* you use it.  Such usage would however render the code non ISO C compliant, and therefore less portable, however due to C++'s standard support for the keyword, you are likely to find it as an extension in most C tool-chains that include C++ compilation, so long as you do not use excessively strict compliance options.

However the error message you are getting is for a different reason.  Unlike C++ in C `struct_tag` alone does not represent a type (if it did, you'd not have needed the `typedef`!), you must use the `struct` keyword.